# Keyboard profile confused between user profiles

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, user-profiles, fast-user-switching

There are several user profiles on my computer. All profiles use English and Czech languages. All users use US QWERTY keyboard for English. Now the interesting part comes:

- I use Czech QWERTY keyboard for Czech
- user X use Czech QWERTZ for Czech

If user X is the only one user logged in, everything works fine. The trouble comes as soon as I log in and then X comes and switches back to his account (I stay logged in).

The user X now has my QWERTY keyboard layout, is spite of his Windows settings showing QWERTZ. When the user X reselects QWERTZ, it has no effect on his profile, however keyboard layout for Czech in my account is changed to QWERTZ!

When X has logged out, my profile stays as QWERTZ. If I try to fix that, things become even more confused.

This is how my settings look when accessed from tray:

> [image: Tray settings]

This is how my settings look from settings:

> [image: Settings - English] [image: Settings - Czech]

You can see tray lists keyboard profiles which are not listed in settings - INTL (US international) and CS (Czech keyboard, which is QWERTZ). Those are leaking from the other profile somehow.

This seems like a bug. Is this a known bug? Is there some workaround?

Comment: I have reported the problem to MS using the feedback app as https://aka.ms/S4ro7d (feedback app link).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but I have one account with czech qwerty layout and another with czech qwertz layout.

The only solution I found is switching to login screen (WIN+L) and then login to your account again. After that is the keyboard layout set correctly. There was working shortcut CTRL+SHIFT which changed keyboard layouts even if you have only one in your account (and different in another). But it doesn't work for me now after some Windows Updates.

Comment: The last sentence seems to be unnecessary in this answer.